# Condition in array results

Tags: python, if-statement, scikit-learn, linear-regression

i'm new into python, so, my question is kind simple.

I have a linear Regression, my ypred returns to me a array like this

```
  yPre2_pred = regressaoPre2.predict(XPre2_test)

  ddf2 = pd.DataFrame({'Realizado': yPre2_test, 'Resultado do modelo': yPre2_pred, 'Variação': 
  yPre2_pred / yPre2_test  -1 })
  r_sq = regressaoPre2.score(xPre2, yPre2)
  r_sqmodelo = regressaoPre2.score(XPre2_test, yPre2_test)

  print(ddf2)

  Realizado  Resultado do modelo  Variação
  43     211.33           279.505979  0.322604
  49     125.84            88.377950 -0.297696
  62      55.57            44.049949 -0.207307
  51      39.68            11.281662 -0.715684
  32     473.58           408.446098 -0.137535
  34     123.92           211.493634  0.706695
  29     441.96           311.487298 -0.295214
  46     317.28           309.504595 -0.024506
  11     122.19           162.888449  0.333075
  2       37.73          -103.208499 -3.735449
  26      40.16            73.811614  0.837939
  60     240.40           184.092869 -0.234223
  4       88.98           -24.397806 -1.274194
```

I need to " if "resultado modelo" (yPre2_pred) below 40, then add 40 to the results.

How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `.apply()` method with a lambda function to modify the dataframe.
For every cell value `x` of your column *Resultado do modelo* you either add 40 to x if `x<40` or return `x`.

```
ddff2["Resultado do modelo"].apply(lambda x: x+40 if x<40 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should add 40 to every cell of the "Resultado do modelo" column, the original value of which is below 40:

```
for i, value in enumerate(ddff2["Resultado do modelo"]):
    if value < 40:
        ddff2.at[i, "Resultado do modelo"] = value + 40
```